# white space on echo " ";

Tags: php

Do not want to correct the code I want why `echo " ";` is not printed in my pyramid shape of `*`?

```
$x = 7;
for($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=$x-$i; ++$j) {
        echo " ";
    }
    for($k=1; $k<=$i; ++$k) {
        echo "* ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Multiple spaces in html generally printed as one space.

Comment: Not sure with your _for_ conditions, but if space is your issue, you can try PHP CLI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose your code in [<pre>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tags to display multiple spaces in the browser. We recommend using "\n" instead of <br>.

```
echo '<pre>'; 
$x = 7;
for($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=$x-$i; ++$j) {
        echo " ";
    }
    for($k=1; $k<=$i; ++$k) {
        echo "* ";
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Alternatively, a special header can also be set with PHP.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Answer (score 1):

The only mistake is on the line break `<br>`. Can you try this?

```
<?php

$x = 7;
for($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=$x-$i; ++$j) {
        echo " ";
    }
    for($k=1; $k<=$i; ++$k) {
        echo "* ";
    }
    echo " \n";
}
```

Comment: Also not working can you tell me the reason only, why echo " "; not printed?